# Simple Concatenation in C

Tags: c, string, concatenation

I'm not good in C, top of that I'm doing after very long, I need to do a very simple thing:

```
char code[]="aasd";
char *rmessage="";
strcat(rmessage,code[0]);
```

I simply want to concatenate the content of index 0 of array `code` to `rmessage`.

Comment: The two declarations are not the same. This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862842/difference-between-char-str-string-and-char-str-string) may help you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to ensure there is enough space in `rmessage` to store the result of the concatentation. You can use [strncat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncat/) to specify the number of characters to copy from a string:

```
char code[] = "aasd";
char rmessage[1024] = "";

strncat(rmessage, code, 1);
```

or, in this case, just assign the first character of `rmessage`:

```
rmessage[0] = code[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Not coding in C for long time.I think the syntax is just correct.

```
int sz=10; // sz = # number of chars you want to store + 1 , i assumed 9 characters will be stored at max. 
char code[] = "aasd";
char *rmessage = malloc(sz*sizeof(char));
rmessage[0]=code[0];
rmessage[1]=NULL;
```

*Remember to deallocate the memory allocated to rmessage after your job is done.

```
free(rmessage);
```