# Why there is no need to allocate memory when declaring string

Tags: c

I am new to C, and currently I am trying to understand how pointers work.

Here is one problem that confuses me:

As far as I know, before assigning a value to pointer, you should allocate certain memory for that pointer (if I am wrong, please correct me :) ), like the code below:

```
int main(void) {
    int i;
    int * ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));

    i = 2;
    *ptr = 5;     
    printfn("%d",*ptr); 
    free(ptr);
}
```

However, when declaring string in C, just like:

```
char *p = "Hello world";
```

without need to allocate memory.

What's the reason and how does it work? If I am missing something, kindly remind me.

Comment: You're missing what the expression *value* of an array is in the C language. It is an *address* (of the first element in the contiguous sequence). And pointers hold: *addresses*. A string literal is a read-only array of `char`. That said (1) [don't cast malloc in C programs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), and (2) if you're assigning a string *literal* to a pointer, use a `const` pointer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004302/how-c-strings-are-allocated-in-memory?rq=1

Comment: Oh god. Is this really a question worth +4? (hint: no.)

Comment: `printfn`? Are you in [F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370571.aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...you should allocate certain memory for that pointer ...

No, you seems to misunderstand about pointers...

Pointer is the type which hold some type's *address*. Look at this example.

```
int a = 1;
int *p = &a;
```

The type of `a` is `int`, which contains *integer*.

The type of `p` is `int *`, which contains *address of integer variables*.

Let's suppose memory like this:

```
--------------------------------------
variables: | a          | p          |
--------------------------------------
address  : | 0x12341234 | 0x12341238 |
--------------------------------------
```

the `&` operator gets *the address of operand*. So, `&a` is equal to `0x12341234`.

So the variables are initialized like this:

```
--------------------------------------
variables: | a          | p          |
--------------------------------------
address  : | 0x12341234 | 0x12341238 |
--------------------------------------
value    : | 1          | 0x12341234 |
--------------------------------------
```

Now, look this code, `*p`. the `*` operator, *dereference operator*, gets the value of *the variables which the pointer is pointing*. In this case, `p` contains `0x12341234` - What variables is in `0x12341234`? the `a`! So `*p` is equal to `1`, which `a` contains.

---

Now look this example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char c1 = '1';

int main()
{
    char c2 = '2';

    char *p1 = &c1;
    char *p2 = &c2;

    char ar[13] = "hello world!"; /* don't forget '\0' : 12 + 1. */

    char *p3 = &ar[0];
    const char *p4 = "hello world!"; /* notice the type, `const char *` */

    char *p5 = malloc(13 * sizeof(char));
}
```

`c1` is global variables, so compiler place it on the *data section* of program directly. `c2` is local variables of `main`, so it is placed on *stack* by `main`. Anyway, they're placed on memory. And `p1` and `p2` contains their *address*, so `*p1` is `'1'` (`c1`) and `*p2` is `'2'` (`c2`).

`ar` is 13-length *array* of `char`. It is placed on memory like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------
|'h'|'e'|'l'|'l'|'o'|' '|'w'|'o'|'r'|'l'|'d'|'!'|'\0'|
------------------------------------------------------
```

And `&ar[0]` is the address of the first element of `ar`, so `p3` contains the address of `'h'`.

Now look at `p4`. It's initialized by `"hello world!"`. Your question is where it is allocated - it's just (string) *constant*, like `1234`, `2.71` or `'a'`. Constant is placed on the program directly, by compiler. Like `c1`, the *string constant* is placed on the ***ro**data section* of program directly. Contrast to *data section*, *rodata section* is read-only (Read Only DATA) because string constant is constant. (As you know, constant is read-only.) So the type of `p4` is `const char *`.

`p5` is initialized by return value of `malloc`, that is from *dynamic allocation*. In this case, `malloc` allocates the memory somewhere, and `p5` is initialied by this.

Answer (score 9):

`char *p = "Hello world";`

you created a pointer and pointed it at a constant string. The compiler puts that in a part of memory that is marked as read-only.

it has no name and has static storage duration (meaning that it lives for the entire life of the program); and a variable of type pointer-to-char, called `p`, which is initialized with the location of the first character in that unnamed, read-only array.

Comment: thanks, I understand what you said, now my question is does compiler will do the same thing with int type (like the example I mentioned)?

Comment: @Justin for single variable `int` you not need to allocate. it will allocate size (sizeof(int)) at run time on stack. For `int` array you can allocate dynamical as you already done or give fix array size.

Comment: just int *ptr; *ptr = 5; is valid or invalid? I think it's invalid, *ptr does not know where should it point to (I mean address).

Comment: @Justin No not valid!!. It just pointer. Not point any memory address. it will cause you segmentation fault.

Answer (score 4):

`"Hello world"` is static data, which is compiled into your binary, just like the `2` and the `5` in your example.

`char * p` is defined to be a pointer to that location in your binary.

Which is also why it should be **`char const`**, as you shouldn't ever *write* to that location. (Your compiler should have given you a warning about this.)