# Pointer assignment to different types

Tags: c

We can assign a string in C as follows:

```
char *string;
string = "Hello";
printf("%s\n", string); // string
printf("%p\n", string); // memory-address
```

And a number can be done as follows:

```
int num = 4404;
int *nump = &num;
printf("%d\n", *nump);
printf("%p\n", nump);
```

My question then is, why can't we assign a pointer to a number in C just like we do with strings? For example, doing:

```
int *num;
num = 4404;
// and the rest...
```

What makes a string fundamentally different than other primitive types? I'm quite new to C so any explanation as to the difference between the two would be very helpful.

Comment: A string in C is stored as an array of characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigning strings to pointer in C Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690475/assigning-strings-to-pointer-in-c-language)

Comment: Just where is `num = 4404;` in a system using randomized addresses? Now, for some embedded boards with fixed address for LEDs, etc., it does make sense, but those are "freestanding systems", not "hosted systems".

Comment: Duplicate: [“Pointer from integer/integer from pointer without a cast” issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues). TL;DR the language simply doesn't allow it, use an explicit cast instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Pointer from integer/integer from pointer without a cast" issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why can't we assign a pointer to a number in C just like we do with strings?

```
int *num;
num = 4404;
```

Code *can* do that **if** 4404 is a valid address for an  `int`.

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
>   entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.
>   C11dr §6.3.2.3 5

If the address is not properly aligned --> *undefined behavior* (UB).
If the address is a trap --> *undefined behavior* (UB).

Attempting to de-reference the pointer is a problem unless it points to a valid `int`.

```
printf("%d\n", *num);
```

---

With below, `"Hello"` is a *string literal*.  It exist someplace. The assignment take the address of the *string literal* and assigns that to `string`.

```
char *string;
string = "Hello";
```

The point is that that address assigned is known to be valid for a `char *`.

In the `num = 4404;` is not known to be valid (it likely is not).

---

> What makes a string fundamentally different than other primitive types?

In C, a *string* is a C library specification, not a C language one.  It is definition convenient to explaining various function therein.

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character §7.1.1 1

Primitive types are part of the  C language.

The languages also has *string literals* like `"Hello"` in `char *string; string = "Hello";`.  These have some similarity to *strings*, yet differ.

---

I recommend searching for "ISO/IEC9899:2017"  to find a draft copy of the current C spec.  It will answer many of your 10 question of the last week.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such type as "string" in C. A string is **not** a primitive type. A string is just an array of characters, terminated by a NUL byte (`'\0'`).

When you do this:

```
char *string;
string = "Hello";
```

What really happens is that the compiler is smart and creates a constant read only `char` array and then assigns it to your variable `string`. This can be done because in C the name of an array is the same as the pointer to its first element.

```
// This is placed in a different section:
const char hidden_arr[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};

char *string;
string = hidden_arr;
// Same as:
string = &(hidden_arr[0]);
```

Here, `hidden_arr` and `string` are both `char *`, because as we just said the name of an array is equal to the pointer to its first element. Of course, all of this is done transparently, you will not actually see another variable named `hidden_arr`, that's just an example. In reality the string will be stored in some location in your executable without a name, and the address of that location will be copied to your `string` pointer.

When you try to do the same with an integer, it's wrong because `int *` and `int` are different types, and you cannot write this (well, you can, but it's meaningless and does not do what you expect it to):

```
int *ptr;
ptr = 123;
```

But, you can very well do it with an *array of integers*:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
int *ptr;
ptr = arr;
// Same as:
ptr = &(arr[0]);
```

Comment: OK explanations, but amiss in detail.  A C _string_ is not an _array_, although a _string literal_ is.  The _string literal_ `"Hello"` is not read-only as much as it is something that should not be written - result is UB - it might work, might not, might kill the code.  `hidden_arr` (the string literal) is not a `char *` as an array is not a pointer and a pointer is not an array.  With `int *ptr; ptr = 123;`, code can do that with very limited value conditions - `int *` and `int` as different types is not the limitation.

Comment: @chux didn't say a char array IS a pointer. I specifically said that the name of a char array and a pointer to its first element are the same thing. doing int *x = 123 will warn you that types mismatch, so it should not be done without a cast. The string literal "hello" might not be required by the standard to be RO, but writing to it is UB, so you might as well consider it RO, which actually usually is, since it's put in a RO section by the compiler.

Comment: "we just said the name of an array is equal to the pointer to its first element." mixes up more the  array/pointer differences --> Counter example: compare `sizeof hidden_arr` and `sizeof (char *)` - they differ - the name of an array is not _always_ equal to pointer to first element.  Warnings are a good indication that something may be amiss, yet maybe not, else the compiler would have error-ed, not simply warned.  Cast does quiet the warning.  A compliant compiler/platform need not have any "read-only" memory - common enough among embedded devices and simple processors to lack that.

Comment: *"compare sizeof hidden_arr and sizeof (char *) - they differ"* I know that very well. This: "the name of an array is equal to the pointer to its first element" is true. There's no difference between `arr` and `&(arr[0])`. Again, I did not say that an array is a pointer, I know those are completely different things. --- As per the string, granted that, but treating it as RO is the only thing you can legally do, so that's what I wrote. This is a simple answer for a beginner, no need to go into the depths of the C standard.

Comment: *"else the compiler would have error-ed, not simply warned"* eh... many many warnings *will* result in runtime errors or UB. Assigning one type to another without doing proper conversion is a very useful warning that should not be ignored. This is just a case where the warning *could* be safely ignored, but it should definitely not be, and again this is just a simple answer for a beginner.

Comment: Marco Bonelli, @Shared is a lively poster - not a typical beginner.  OP does not need [over simplified answers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children) with are factual wrong as with "it's wrong because int * and int are different types, and you cannot write `int *ptr;
ptr = 123;`".  Simplified answers are good - IMO, this one edged over in incorrectly  various ways.

Comment: @chux well, I get the point. Feel free to edit to my answer if you want, something could be perhaps rephrased better to stay clear and also be 100% correct.

Answer (score 1):

> What makes a string fundamentally different than other primitive types?

A string *seems* like a primitive type in C because the compiler understands `"foo"` and generates a null-terminated character array: `['f', 'o', 'o', '\0']`. But a C string is still just that: an array of characters.

> My question then is, why can't we assign a pointer to a number in C just like we do with strings?

You certainly can assign a pointer to a number, it's just that a number isn't a pointer, whereas the *value* of an array is the address of the array. If you had an array of `int`, then that would work just like a string. Compare your code:

```
char *string;
string = "Hello";
printf("%s\n", string); // string
printf("%p\n", string); // memory-address
```

to the analogous code for an array of integers:

```
int numbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0};
int *nump = numbers;
printf("%d\n", nump[0]); // string
printf("%p\n", nump);    // memory-address
```

The only real difference is that the compiler has some extra syntax for arrays of characters because they're so common, and `printf()` similarly has a format specifier just for character arrays for the same reason.

Comment: thanks for this. Especially helpful is this part to understanding it: `The only real difference is that the compiler has some extra syntax for arrays of characters because they're so common, and printf() similarly has a format specifier just for character arrays for the same reason.`

Answer (score 0):

The type pf a string literal (e.g. "hello world") is a `char[]`. Where assigning `char *string = "Hello"` means that `string` now points to the start of the array (e.g. the address of the first memory address in the array: `&char[0]`).

Whereas you can't assign an integer to a pointer because their types are different, one is a `int` the other is a pointer `int *`. You could cast it to the correct type:

```
int *num;
num = (int *) 4404;
```

But this would be considered quite dangerous (unless you really know what you are doing). I.e. do you know what is a memory adress `4404`?