# I don't understand this use of pointers

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand this use of pointers. From what I realized so far the value pointers hold is a reference to the memory address of another entity, and when using the `*` sign we access the value of the entity referenced by the pointer.

However, in this code that I encountered in the tutorial i'm using, the `ptr_str`pointer has a string value which is not a memory address, so I don't understand how `*ptr_str` (which I expected to be the value of a referenced entity) is used in the for loop.

```
char *ptr_str; int i;
ptr_str = "Assign a string to a pointer.";
for (i=0; *ptr_str; i++)
    printf("%c", *ptr_str++);
```

Comment: `the ptr_str pointer has a string value which is not a memory address` It is.

Comment: "Assign a strin gto a pointer" is a character array somewhere in memory ant ptr_string points to the address of the first character. Then the loop prints each character incrementing the address by one in every iteration.

Comment: The value of a string-constant is a pointer to the first `char`.

Comment: In C all literal strings are really *arrays* of (read-only) characters including the terminating "null" character `'\0'`. Your assignment `ptr_str` makes the variable `ptr_str` point to the first element of such an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
ptr_str = "Assign a string to a pointer.";
```

Is a shorthand for this:

```
// Somewhere else:
char real_str[] = {'A', 's', 's', 'i', 'g', ..., '.', '\0'};

// In your main():
ptr_str = real_str;
// or
ptr_str = &real_str[0];
```

In other words, string literals like `"Hello World"` are actually pointers to a character array holding your string. This is all done transparently by the compiler, so it might be confusing at first sight.

If you're curious, take a look at [this other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57765391/3889449), where I explain this in more detail.

Comment: Don't forget that it is undefined behaviour to modify a string literal (even though they are not actually `const`) and that they have static scope so you can return them from a function (where returning an array can cause undefined behaviour). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493139/are-string-literals-const