# Why does a "char array" require two of "[]" but an "int array" requires one "[]"?

Tags: c, arrays, char, int

In a `char` array, you are required to have 2 of `[]`. One of them is for storing the **array index number** and the other one is for storing the **value** for that index:

```
char u[1][50];

strcpy(u[0],"test");
strcpy(u[1],"test 2");

printf("%s \n",u[1]);
```

But, in an `int` array you just need one `[]`.

Is it for the **array index number** or is it for the **value**?

Regardless of the answer to that question … Why isn't there 2 of `[]`?

```
int z[100];

z[0] = 1;
z[1] = 2;

printf("%d \n",z[1]);
```

Why must there be "full accountability" for the `char` array but, for the `int` array, there does not need to be "full accountability"?

Why are there 2 standards?

Maybe you do not need "full accountability" for arrays?
Maybe the array's index number is considered default, organic and free stuff?

Well then in such case, for the `char` array, why are two of `[]` required?

Comment: it's not required, but a `char[]` could be considered a `string`, and consequentially, a `char[][]` is `string[]` aka an array of strings.

Comment: @Shark *a `char[][]` is `string[]` aka an array of strings*  No, just no.  Lose the CS50 `string` abomination. Permanently. Hiding a pointer behind a `typedef` is misleading - at best.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57765755/12062404 This question gets asked a lot. A simple web search would give you a number of links to C tutorials that would answer your question, see this for example: https://overiq.com/c-programming-101/array-of-strings-in-c/

Comment: @AndrewHenle i agree, and never mentioned any `typedef`s in there, was just trying to explain that a string is a `char[]`, and that a `char[][]` is an array of such "strings". and pointed out that a char array does not need two `[]`, but just one - but the purpose for which it is used, which is usually an array of strings - requires two.

Comment: "In a char array you are required to have 2 of []" --> No.  `char u[1][50];` is not a `char` array but an [array 1 of array 50 of char](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+u%5B1%5D%5B50%5D%3B), a 2D array of `char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays in C follow this notation:

```
type array_name[num_elements];
type array_name[num_rows][num_elements];
...
```

So in your case you may want to have:

```
int z[100];
```

would be an array of 100 ints. To access any of them you use z[0] for the first int, z[1] for the second int, etc. till z[99].

Similarly you may want to have an array of chars like such:

```
char u[50];
```

to access the first character you use u[0], etc.

When it comes to multidimensional arrays, you may have:

```
char u[10][50];
```

which means you have 10 rows of 50 elements each. You can also call them strings, so 10 strings.

To access the first string you use u[0]. The last string is at u[9].

Now for each string you can access their elements like such: u[0][1] to access the second element of the first string.

strcpy requires as its first argument a string. So if you have u[10][50], you can pass u[9], which would be last string. You should not pass u[9][2] which would be the third char from the last string.

What you did is u[1][50], which means you so happen to have only 1 row in your list of strings. You still need to follow the same rules as for multidimensional arrays even though it is 1 string only. Normally you'd use u[50] and just pass u to strcpy

Answer (score 9):

You don't need two `[]`:

```
int main() {
    char u[50];
    strcpy(u, "test");
    printf("%s \n", u);
}
```

It's just that strings are represented by a pointer to a character, so passing one `char` doesn't work. You tried that anyway, and then you changed the definition of the string to a multidimensional `char` array. This is redundant and causes issues when you do this:

```
char u[1][50];
strcpy(u[1],"test 2");
```

which is undefined behavior as the first array index has to be `0`.

Perhaps your confusion comes from the comparison with `int`. If you want to print one `char`, use the `%c` format specifier (and then pass a `char`, not a `char*`). If you do that, it will be just like the `int` example:

```
int main() {
    char z[100];

    z[0] = '1';
    z[1] = '2';

    printf("%c \n", z[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> ...Regardless of the answer to that question..
>   Why isn't there 2 of [] ?

Semantics may be affecting your understanding of arrays and their indexing requirements.  `C` has arrays for `int` and `char`, each requiring a single set of `[]` to define.  There is a special kind of `char` array in `C` commonly referred to as a `C String`, which is just a regular `char` array with the last character being the null terminator: `\0`.  An array of `C strings` does commonly use two sets of brackets: `[][]`.
The rules for representing a `char` array are the same as those for representing an `int` array.  both can be described as a collection of values stored in a contiguous set of memory locations.  To illustrate, example arrays of `int`, `char` and a `C string` follow:

```
int  numarr[]   = {99,104,97,114,32,97,114,114,97,121,0};
char chararr1[] = {'c','h','a','r',' ','a','r','r','a','y','\0'};
char chararr2[] = {99,104,97,114,32,97,114,114,97,121,0};
char string[]   = {"char array"};
```

The array values in each of the 4 examples above are identical.  In most implementations, the `int` array is stored in a contiguous set 4 byte memory locations, while each of the `char` arrays are stored in a contiguous set of 1 byte memory locations. The three `char` arrays, if used in `printf()` would result in the same *string* output, as each is an array of `char` terminated with a null value.

```
printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", chararr1, chararr2, string);
```

> char array
>   char array
>   char array

More about the special `char` array - *C string*, and arrays of *C string*

```
char string[] = {"this is a string"};
```

A *C string* is defined an a null terminated array of `char`:  The content de-marked between `^` is `string` defined above.  Note the null termination.

```
|t|h|i|s| |i|s| |a| |s|t|r|i|n|g|\0|?|?|
^                                  ^
```

A contiguous set of C strings, or *array of C strings* however can be represented by using two set of square brackets:

```
char strings[2][20] = {"first string", "second string"};
```

This array of string would look like this in memory:

```
|f|i|r|s|t| |s|t|r|i|n|g|\0|s|e|c|o|n|d| |s|t|r|i|n|g|\0|?|?|?|
|       |           |      |
[0]     |           |      [1]   1st index used to access full string
        [0][4]='t'  [0][10]='n'  2nd index used to access array elements
```

While each string can be accessed by using the first index,

```
eg. strings[0] = "first string" and strings[1] = "second string"
```

each character of each string can be accessed using the first and second index

```
eg. strings[0][0] == 'f'  and strings[1][0] == 's'
```

Answer (score 1):

> Well then in such case..
>
> for the char array why are two of [] required ?

It is not required...

Your confusion seems to come from the way string (aka text strings) are handled in C.

In C a string is a **char array** with the special requirement that a char in the array has the value NUL (aka `'\0'`). That special char represents end-of-string.

So in order to make an **array of strings**, you'll have to use "two []" - example:

```
char myStrings[10][101];
```

The variable `myStrings` can hold 10 strings and each of these can be up to 100 characters long (note: not 101 because you need one char for holding the special NUL character).

If you just do:

```
char someCharArray[101];
```

you can use it to store **one** string (max len 100) **or** use it for storing 101 individual chars.

Answer (score 0):

You’re using `u` to store an array<sup>1</sup> of *strings*, where each string can be up to 49 characters in length.

C doesn’t have an actual string type - in C, a string is a sequence of character values including a 0-valued terminator.  Strings are stored as arrays of character type (`char` for ASCII, EBCDIC, or UTF-8 character encodings, `wchar_t` for "wide" encodings).  So to store an array of *strings*, you need a 2D array of character type (or a 1D array of pointers to character type, where each element stores the address of another array, but we won’t get into that here).

So,

```
char name[51];
```

can store a *single* string up to 50 characters long (with an extra element for the 0 terminator):

```
printf( "Gimme a name: " );
scanf( "%s", name );
```

Compare that to

```
char names[10][51];
```

which can store up to 10 strings, each of which can be up to 50 characters in length:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
  printf( "Gimme a string: ");
  scanf( "%s", names[i] );
}
```

---

1. Actually, your declaration for `u` only allows for a single array element - `strcpy(u[1], “test 2”);` is attempting to copy the string to the memory following `u`, which results in undefined behavior.